# Code-First generated code doesn't work

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, code-first

I'm using database first, after I read about Entity Framework future then I decided to convert to code first using VS2015 wizard (code-first from database).

This is my database diagram:

[image].

The generated code hasn't mapped the table `FinancialSell` like was in `.edmx`. But it doesn't put any configuration. This is the generated code:

```
public partial class XContext : DbContext
{
    public XContext()
        : base("name=XContext")
    {
    }

    public virtual DbSet<Financial> Financial { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Sell> Sell { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
    }
}

[Table("Sell")]
public partial class Sell
{
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
    public Sell()
    {
        Financial = new HashSet<Financial>();
    }

    public int ID { get; set; }

    public decimal Value { get; set; }

    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<Financial> Financial { get; set; }
}


[Table("Financial")]
public partial class Financial
{
    public int ID { get; set; }

    public DateTime Date { get; set; }

    public virtual Sell Sell { get; set; }
}
```

When i tried to use for a simple interaction:

```
 var sell = new Sell {Value = 1.00M};
        var financ = new Financial {Date = DateTime.Now, Sell = sell};

        using(var ctx = new XContext())
        {
            ctx.Financial.Add(financ);
            ctx.SaveChanges();

            Console.WriteLine("Ok Success!");
        }
```

An exception is raised:

> An error occurred while saving entities that do not expose foreign key properties for their relationships. The EntityEntries property will return null because a single entity cannot be identified as the source of the exception. Handling of exceptions while saving can be made easier by exposing foreign key properties in your entity types. See the InnerException for details.

**Inner Exception**

> Invalid column name 'Sell_ID'.

Comment: Well, what does the `InnerException` say?

Comment: Are you just going with the edmx classes? You will probably need to add some annotations or fluent code for the relationships. You might want to reverse engineer it (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj200620.aspx).

Comment: The presence of that third table implies a many-to-many relationship, but since it appears the primary key of the `FinancialSell` table is linked to the primary key of the `Financial` table, each `Financial` record can only ever be mapped to single `Sell`.  If this is the desired implementation, you'll need to add some configuration in the `OnModelCreating` method, as Steve mentioned.

Comment: you have a `virtual Sell Sell { get; set; }` but you don't have an `int SellID { get; set; }`. I believe you need a foreign key to link the tables, not just a reference to them.

Comment: it was generated per VS2015 "Code First from database" wizard, and i don't know how configure using Fluent API, i found samples but don't work for me

Comment: When you reverse engineer it should create the POCO's plus a model class with the fluent code. You need to make sure you don't name the model the same as any of the tables.

Answer (score 0):

I am sorry but I can't provide it in C# for you :) But you should be able to fine a converter out there that'll do you right.

```
Imports System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations
Imports System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema
Imports System.Data.Entity

Module Module1

    Sub Main()

    Dim sell = New Sell() With {
        .Value = 1D
    }
    Dim financ = New Financial() With {
        .[Date] = DateTime.Now,
        .Sell = sell
    }

    Using ctx = New XContext()
        ctx.Financials.Add(financ)
        ctx.FinancialSells.Add(New FinancialSell With {.Financial = financ, .Sell = sell})
        ctx.SaveChanges()

        Console.WriteLine("Ok Success!")
    End Using
End Sub

End Module
Partial Public Class XContext
Inherits DbContext

Public Sub New()
    'Recreates your database when it changes.
    Database.SetInitializer(Of XContext)(New DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges(Of XContext)())
    'MyBase.New("name=XContext")
End Sub

    Public Overridable Property Financials As DbSet(Of Financial)
    Public Overridable Property Sells As DbSet(Of Sell)
    Public Overridable Property FinancialSells As DbSet(Of FinancialSell)

    Protected Overrides Sub OnModelCreating(modelBuilder As DbModelBuilder)
    modelBuilder.Entity(Of FinancialSell)().HasRequired(Function(x) x.Sell).WithMany().WillCascadeOnDelete(False)
End Sub
End Class

<Table("Sell")>
Partial Public Class Sell
    <System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")>
    Public Sub New()
        Financial = New HashSet(Of Financial)()
    End Sub

    <Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity), ScaffoldColumn(False)>
    Public Property ID As Integer
    Public Property Value As Decimal

    <System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")>
    Public Overridable Property Financial As ICollection(Of Financial)

End Class


<Table("Financial")>
Partial Public Class Financial
    <Key, Column(Order:=0), DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity), ScaffoldColumn(False)>
    Public Property ID As Integer
    Public Property [Date] As DateTime
    <Column(Order:=1), ForeignKey("Sell")>
    Public Property SellID As Integer

    'Navigation Properties
    Public Overridable Property Sell As Sell

End Class

Partial Public Class FinancialSell
    <Key, Column(Order:=0), ForeignKey("Financial")>
    Public Property FinancialID As Integer
    <Key, Column(Order:=1), ForeignKey("Sell")>
    Public Property SellID As Integer

    'Navigation Properties
    Public Overridable Property Sell As Sell
    Public Overridable Property Financial As Financial
End Class
```

Comment: Ok but i need to keep database model, the application are in production. My table FinancialSell has a a PK/FK called ID from Financial and SellID as FK from Sell